# Develop a chrome extension to count <input> tags of currently accessed webpage

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

Hey I'm new to javascript and chrome extension developing. I'm trying to develop a chrome extension which use browser action to count the number of  tags in currently active tab of the Google Chrome browser.I can use getElementsByTagName.lenght method to calculate the number of tags and I know that I can use console API to access the DOM of a webpage. But I have no idea how to call that API from my javascript file.Do you guys know anything regarding this ?

Comment: Start with the [Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview).

Answer (score 0):

To get access to the current page DOM you need to write a content script.
1. Specify the content script in manifest.json

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ]
```

If you need to inject the script sometimes use Programmatic Injection by specifying permissions field:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  ...
}
```

2.I would prefer the latter in this case.In popup.js add the code:

```
function printResult(result){
//or You can print the result using innerHTML
console.log(result);

}
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: 'content.js' },function(result){
   printResult(result);
});
```

3.In content script u have access to current page/active tab DOM.

```
var result=document.getElementsByTagName("input").length;
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `getBackgroundPage`, and it's harmful advice to use it because it will not work with Event pages.

Comment: You're using a lot of unneeded boilerplate (what is `init` for?), you never deregister your message listener in the background (causing `callback` to be called N times on N-th call to `getResult`. I see that you're trying to help, but this answer needs work.

Comment: I recommend using the return value of the content script in the callback of `executeScript` instead of messaging, you won't need to de-register handlers this way.

Comment: @Xan Thanks for the advice.Actually I am new to chrome Extension development.Is my code correct now??

Comment: Almost. Why do you need the background page at all here? No need for messaging, just do `executeScript` from the popup. And `"activeTab"` permission is much better.

Comment: Looks okay now. Note that the callback of `executeScript` does not look for a `result` variable in the executed script, it just collects the last evaluated expression. Also, `result` in the callback is an array of results - you might want to print `result[0]`